# mod_rewrite not allowing a-z

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So here is my question..

This is the url I have: 
/category.php?cat=8

this is the url im trying to achieve: 
/parties-events/kitchen/

Within the database the category has a  id, **main**, **sub**, **main_slug** and **sub_slug**

This: /**main_slug**/**sub_slug**/

I had this

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ category.php?param=$1&param2=$2 [NC]
```

Which outputs and works fine: /category/8/

BUT.. It only works with numbers, nothing else. I get a not found page if I use and letters.

But I'm lost as to the htaccess regex to just use the main and sub slugs and not only numbers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you please show me an example?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(\w+)\/(\w+)/?$ category.php?param=$1&param2=$2 [L,QSA]`

Comment: So the page loads now but only recognizes the number and not the text slug.. hmm..

Answer (score 1):

In this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ category.php?param=$1&param2=$2 [NC]
```

The `([a-z]+)` bit means "one or more letters between a and z"

The `([0-9]+)` bit means "one or more numbers between 0 and 9"

It appears that what you are asking will be accomplished by replacing the `[0-9]` with another `[a-z]`. However, if you want to accept *any* character, and not just a-z and/or 0-9, replace both of them with just `([^/]+)` which means "one or more not-slash characters".

Comment: Or, as @anubhava suggests, you could use \w which means "word characters" which matches a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and the underscore "_" character. It all depends on how restrictive you want to be.

Comment: I got it to load the page now using letters but my query is still only reading numbers and not the text slug. $_REQUEST['param2']. any ideas why that would be?